# Is it possible to share a single Redis server over multiple micro services on GKE?

Tags: go, redis, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a redis-service running a redis server. Should I be able to store and retrieve data to that service from multiple clients on different services? I have been unsuccessful in my experiments thus far.

I have a compute-service in its own pod that dials the redis-service and stores a key/value

```
rClient := redis.NewClient(&redis.Options{
    Addr:     "redis-service:6379",
    Password: "", // no password set
    DB:       0,  // use default DB
})

rClient.Set("trump", "value", 0).Err()
```

I then have a web-service in its own pod that tries to read this value. Error returns Nil and the value is blank.

```
rClient := redis.NewClient(&redis.Options{
    Addr:     "redis-service:6379",
    Password: "", // no password set
    DB:       0,  // use default DB
})

val, err := rClient.Get("trump").Result()

fmt.Fprintf(w, "Print Error: %v \n", err) //prints nil

fmt.Fprintf(w, "Print Value: %s \n", val) // blank
```

If I set the value in the web-service then I can read the value fine. I just cant seem to set the value in a different service. As far as I know Redis stores data on the server side which would be redis-service.

Here is my redis-service deployment/service yaml files. Maybe it is the configuration?

```
   apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: redis-service
  labels:
    app: redis-service
    role: master
    tier: backend
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 6379
    targetPort: 6379
  selector:
    app: redis-service


apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: redis-service
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: redis-service
      role: master
      tier: backend
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: redis-service
        role: master
        tier: backend
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: redis-service
        image: k8s.gcr.io/redis:e2e  # or just image: redis
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 100Mi
        ports:
        - containerPort: 6379
```

Comment: Did you make sure that the Set did not return an error?

Comment: @jmaloney I am sure I must have at some point but will check again as obviously that would tell me if I can set from my compute service or not.

Comment: @jmaloney so err is returning nil when i try setting key/value in the compute service. My guess is it is writing to client side cache not server. I am still trying to find online whether or not this is how Redis normally works.

Comment: I don't see `redis-service` in your yaml file, try connecting to redis with just `redis:6379`

Comment: You are correct. I have been making a lot of changes to try get this to work. It should say redis-service in the yaml. So even with the changes I am still not able to set key/value in my compute-service. I will fix that in the OP

Comment: Do you deploy redis and your app in the same namespace?

Comment: @MaciekSawicki No they are Deployed in their own pods with their own ClusterIP. My current design pattern is that the web-service takes a variable from a web form and send it to the compute-service. The compute-service the Dial

Comment: .....dials the redis-service and saves a key/value. In the web-service there is a http handler that can be called to retrieve the value from the redis-service. Both compute and web service dial the redis-service in the exact same way. I am also having an issues using a mysql database with this same setup.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been resolved. I set the Image pull policy to always in my compute-service deployment yaml. I also changed its port from :9090 to 8080 thinking the port might have been used elsewhere. Finally I upgraded my GCP account from a trial. I am not sure exactly which one of these fixed the issue but I am relieved it is resolved now.